# CSS Menu stuck behind an iframe

Tags: css, iframe, drop-down-menu

I'm pretty inexperienced at programming. But I made a website that works as a portfolio for work. I have separate PDF files that are loaded into an iframe (placed in an ap div) that you can scroll through. The site is www.michaellautner.com and the Architecture page is where the problem occurs (if you want to see the set up). The menu at the top is where the problem occurs. The one that is up now I gave up on, as it was a spry menu I made in dreamweaver and apparently isn't supported any longer?. I made a new menu bar on a free CSS menu creator site that I could plug in. The problem is the Menu entitled "School" drops down behind the iframe and can't be seen. Works fine in Firefox but won't work in IE10. Here is the code... been working at this for almost 2 weeks on aand off and am getting no help from the menu site. I have also played with the z-index with no success and tried changing the divs position to relative but it messes up the entire page. Any help would be wonderful...

(I highlighted the div for the menu and div for the iframe)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Architecture</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--Fireworks CS3 Dreamweaver CS3 target.  Created Tue Jun 25 00:04:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 2013-->
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<!--
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}
function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

//-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">

body,td,th {
    font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
body {
    background-image: url(Images/Background_Image_Arch.jpg);
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:304px;
    top:144px;
    width:399px;
    height:62px;
    z-index:1;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#apDiv2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:261px;
    top:195px;
    width:960px;
    height:500px;
    z-index:2;
}
#apDiv3 {
    position:absolute;
    left:261px;
    top:201px;
    width:960px;
    height:500px;
    z-index:2;
}
#apDiv4 {
    position:absolute;
    left:649px;
    top:86px;
    width:181px;
    height:28px;
    z-index:3;
}
#apDiv5 {
    position:absolute;
    left:295px;
    top:162px;
    width:513px;
    height:35px;
    z-index:10;
}
#apDiv6 {
    position:absolute;
    left:489px;
    top:162px;
    width:447px;
    height:40px;
    z-index:5;
}
</style>
<link href="Scripts/menu_assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" onload="MM_preloadImages('Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r1_c3_f2.png','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c8_f2.png','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c9_f2.png','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c10_f2.png','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r5_c2_f2.png','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r6_c2_f2.png');">
**<div id="apDiv3"><iframe src="file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/3D%20Models%20and%20Renderings/index.html" style="border:0px;" name="archi_frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height ="650px" width ="950px">
</iframe></div>**
<div id="apDiv4"><a href="mailto:mlautner03@yahoo.com" target="_blank">mike@michaellautner.com</a></div>
**<div id="apDiv5"><div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/3D%20Models%20and%20Renderings/index.html' target="archi_frame1"><span>3D Models & Renderings</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Subpages/commercial/commercial.htm'><span>Commercial</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Subpages/residential/residential.htm'><span>Residential</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>School</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/School/Boathouse/index.html'target="archi_frame1"><span>Boathouse</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/School/Chippewa%20Building/index.html'target="archi_frame1"><span>Chippewa Building</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/School/Light%20Gallery/index.html'target="archi_frame1"><span>Light Gallery</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/School/Museum/index.html' target="archi_frame1"><span>Museum</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div> </div>**
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1152">
  <!-- fwtable fwsrc="Master Arch.png" fwpage="Page 1" fwbase="architecture.png" fwstyle="Dreamweaver" fwdocid = "1462477606" fwnested="0" -->
  <tr>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="20" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="8" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="84" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="69" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="31" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="47" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="20" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="98" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="127" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="206" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="442" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td rowspan="4" colspan="2"><img name="architecture_r1_c1" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r1_c1.png" width="28" height="236" border="0" id="architecture_r1_c1" alt="" /></td>
   <td><a href="index.htm" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r1_c3','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r1_c3_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r1_c3" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r1_c3.png" width="84" height="49" border="0" id="architecture_r1_c3" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td rowspan="2" colspan="8"><img name="architecture_r1_c4" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r1_c4.png" width="1040" height="120" border="0" id="architecture_r1_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="49" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="3"><img name="architecture_r2_c3" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r2_c3.png" width="84" height="187" border="0" id="architecture_r2_c3" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="71" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2" colspan="4"><img name="architecture_r3_c4" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c4.png" width="167" height="116" border="0" id="architecture_r3_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><a href="Master Pages/PDFs/Resume_Lautner, Michael.pdf" target="_blank" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r3_c8','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c8_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r3_c8" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c8.png" width="98" height="44" border="0" id="architecture_r3_c8" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td><a href="Master Pages/PDFs/References_Lautner, Michael.pdf" target="_blank" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r3_c9','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c9_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r3_c9" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c9.png" width="127" height="44" border="0" id="architecture_r3_c9" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td><a href="Master Pages/PDFs/Recommendation_Schneider.pdf" target="_blank" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r3_c10','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c10_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r3_c10" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c10.png" width="206" height="44" border="0" id="architecture_r3_c10" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td rowspan="2"><img name="architecture_r3_c11" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c11.png" width="442" height="116" border="0" id="architecture_r3_c11" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="44" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><img name="architecture_r4_c8" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r4_c8.png" width="431" height="72" border="0" id="architecture_r4_c8" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="72" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="3"><img name="architecture_r5_c1" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r5_c1.png" width="20" height="448" border="0" id="architecture_r5_c1" alt="" /></td>
   <td colspan="4"><a href="graphic.htm" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r5_c2','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r5_c2_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r5_c2" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r5_c2.png" width="192" height="63" border="0" id="architecture_r5_c2" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td rowspan="3"><img name="architecture_r5_c6" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r5_c6.png" width="47" height="448" border="0" id="architecture_r5_c6" alt="" /></td>
   <td rowspan="3" colspan="5"      ><p style="margin:0px">&nbsp;</p></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="63" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><a href="photo.htm" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r6_c2','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r6_c2_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r6_c2" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r6_c2.png" width="161" height="64" border="0" id="architecture_r6_c2" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td rowspan="2"><img name="architecture_r6_c5" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r6_c5.png" width="31" height="385" border="0" id="architecture_r6_c5" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="64" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><img name="architecture_r7_c2" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r7_c2.png" width="161" height="321" border="0" id="architecture_r7_c2" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="321" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
#cssmenu{ height:37px; display:block; padding:0; margin: 0;  border:1px solid; border-radius:5px; } 
#cssmenu > ul {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; float:left; display:block; position:relative;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{
    outline:none;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    padding:12px 20px;
    font:bold 13px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
    z-index: 99;
} 
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a{border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{ content:''; position:absolute; border-right:1px solid; top:-1px; bottom:-1px; right:-2px; z-index:99; } 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after{top:0; bottom:0;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{ content:''; position:absolute; top:18px; right:6px; border:5px solid transparent; border-top:5px solid #fff; } 
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:19px;} 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a{ background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#3f3f3f; padding-bottom:13px; padding-top:13px; top:-1px; z-index:999; } 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > ul, #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > div{display:block;} 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:hover{background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#3f3f3f;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul, #cssmenu ul li > div{ display:none; width:auto; position:absolute; top:38px; padding:10px 0; background:#3f3f3f; border-radius:0 0 5px 5px; z-index:999; } 
#cssmenu ul li > ul{width:200px;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul li{display:block; list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; position:relative;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul li a{ outline:none; display:block; position:relative; margin:0; padding:8px 20px; font:10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); } 


#cssmenu, #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li a:hover{ background:transparent; background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #222222 100%); background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#333333), color-stop(100%,#222222)); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); background:linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#222222',GradientType=0 ); } 
#cssmenu{border-color:#000;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{border-right:1px solid #000; color:#fff;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{border-color:#444;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover{background:#111;}
```

Comment: It works on my IE 10...

Answer (score 1):

After looking at it, the UL needs the z-index and not the cssmenu, I added it in the code
http://jsfiddle.net/N9VAX/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Architecture</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--Fireworks CS3 Dreamweaver CS3 target.  Created Tue Jun 25 00:04:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 2013-->
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<!--
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}
function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

//-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">

body,td,th {
    font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
body {
    background-image: url(Images/Background_Image_Arch.jpg);
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:304px;
    top:144px;
    width:399px;
    height:62px;
    z-index:1;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#apDiv2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:261px;
    top:195px;
    width:960px;
    height:500px;
    z-index:2;
}
#apDiv3 {
    position:absolute;
    left:261px;
    top:201px;
    width:960px;
    height:500px;
    z-index:2;
}
#apDiv4 {
    position:absolute;
    left:649px;
    top:86px;
    width:181px;
    height:28px;
    z-index:3;
}
#apDiv5 {
    position:absolute;
    left:295px;
    top:162px;
    width:513px;
    height:35px;
    z-index:10;
}
#apDiv6 {
    position:absolute;
    left:489px;
    top:162px;
    width:447px;
    height:40px;
    z-index:5;
}
</style>
<link href="Scripts/menu_assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" onload="MM_preloadImages('Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r1_c3_f2.png','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c8_f2.png','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c9_f2.png','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c10_f2.png','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r5_c2_f2.png','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r6_c2_f2.png');">
**<div id="apDiv3"><iframe src="file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/3D%20Models%20and%20Renderings/index.html" style="border:0px;" name="archi_frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height ="650px" width ="950px">
</iframe></div>**
<div id="apDiv4"><a href="mailto:mlautner03@yahoo.com" target="_blank">mike@michaellautner.com</a></div>
**<div id="apDiv5"><div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/3D%20Models%20and%20Renderings/index.html' target="archi_frame1"><span>3D Models & Renderings</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Subpages/commercial/commercial.htm'><span>Commercial</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Subpages/residential/residential.htm'><span>Residential</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>School</span></a>
      <ul style="z-index:99;">
         <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/School/Boathouse/index.html'target="archi_frame1"><span>Boathouse</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/School/Chippewa%20Building/index.html'target="archi_frame1"><span>Chippewa Building</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/School/Light%20Gallery/index.html'target="archi_frame1"><span>Light Gallery</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Graphic%20Design%20Projects/Website_mlautner/Images/Architectural%20Images/School/Museum/index.html' target="archi_frame1"><span>Museum</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div> </div>**
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1152">
  <!-- fwtable fwsrc="Master Arch.png" fwpage="Page 1" fwbase="architecture.png" fwstyle="Dreamweaver" fwdocid = "1462477606" fwnested="0" -->
  <tr>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="20" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="8" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="84" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="69" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="31" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="47" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="20" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="98" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="127" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="206" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="442" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td rowspan="4" colspan="2"><img name="architecture_r1_c1" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r1_c1.png" width="28" height="236" border="0" id="architecture_r1_c1" alt="" /></td>
   <td><a href="index.htm" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r1_c3','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r1_c3_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r1_c3" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r1_c3.png" width="84" height="49" border="0" id="architecture_r1_c3" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td rowspan="2" colspan="8"><img name="architecture_r1_c4" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r1_c4.png" width="1040" height="120" border="0" id="architecture_r1_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="49" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="3"><img name="architecture_r2_c3" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r2_c3.png" width="84" height="187" border="0" id="architecture_r2_c3" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="71" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2" colspan="4"><img name="architecture_r3_c4" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c4.png" width="167" height="116" border="0" id="architecture_r3_c4" alt="" /></td>
   <td><a href="Master Pages/PDFs/Resume_Lautner, Michael.pdf" target="_blank" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r3_c8','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c8_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r3_c8" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c8.png" width="98" height="44" border="0" id="architecture_r3_c8" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td><a href="Master Pages/PDFs/References_Lautner, Michael.pdf" target="_blank" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r3_c9','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c9_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r3_c9" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c9.png" width="127" height="44" border="0" id="architecture_r3_c9" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td><a href="Master Pages/PDFs/Recommendation_Schneider.pdf" target="_blank" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r3_c10','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c10_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r3_c10" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c10.png" width="206" height="44" border="0" id="architecture_r3_c10" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td rowspan="2"><img name="architecture_r3_c11" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r3_c11.png" width="442" height="116" border="0" id="architecture_r3_c11" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="44" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><img name="architecture_r4_c8" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r4_c8.png" width="431" height="72" border="0" id="architecture_r4_c8" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="72" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="3"><img name="architecture_r5_c1" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r5_c1.png" width="20" height="448" border="0" id="architecture_r5_c1" alt="" /></td>
   <td colspan="4"><a href="graphic.htm" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r5_c2','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r5_c2_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r5_c2" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r5_c2.png" width="192" height="63" border="0" id="architecture_r5_c2" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td rowspan="3"><img name="architecture_r5_c6" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r5_c6.png" width="47" height="448" border="0" id="architecture_r5_c6" alt="" /></td>
   <td rowspan="3" colspan="5"      ><p style="margin:0px">&nbsp;</p></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="63" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><a href="photo.htm" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('architecture_r6_c2','','Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r6_c2_f2.png',1);"><img name="architecture_r6_c2" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r6_c2.png" width="161" height="64" border="0" id="architecture_r6_c2" alt="" /></a></td>
   <td rowspan="2"><img name="architecture_r6_c5" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r6_c5.png" width="31" height="385" border="0" id="architecture_r6_c5" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="64" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><img name="architecture_r7_c2" src="Master Pages/images_arch/architecture_r7_c2.png" width="161" height="321" border="0" id="architecture_r7_c2" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="Master Pages/images_arch/spacer.gif" width="1" height="321" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i would also add that using z-index you will need a posistion attribute.

Comment: I tried changing the z-index's but it didn't work. The div containing the menu has a z-index of 10, which is higher then the rest. Can you expand on your initial comment? I'm a total newbie and need my hand held a little. I'm not sure how to set a style to the div itself and not sure where in my code to enter the cssmenu code you wrote. Thanks for responding, appreciate it.

Comment: ... I just added the css style that is assosicated to the menu within the div. Maybe it's something within that.

Comment: I copied the code into the file in dreamweaver and still didn't work. I have moved the div down on the page and the menu does work, it just drops down behind everything. grrrr... any other ideas?